# Hide an API key on a Windows-based PC? Best practices

Tags: windows, bash

I am a new programmer. In my development courses and for personal projects, I use a Mac. So when I need to call an API key, I put that key in my .bash-profile.

I am now trying to program on a Windows based system. Where can I put this key? Is there an equivalent .bash-profile for Windows, and how do I access it? Any help is appreciated. If you can even just tell me what to Google, that would be fine too. I've tried searching but without much luck. This is just going to be for a very simple one-page web application for practice.

Comment: I guess the obvious answer would be an environment variable, but is the hiding aspect a major concern? What sort of skills and access do the people have who may be trying to find it?

Comment: Assuming that your Windows installation is running off of an NTFS drive, I would suggest using [File Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163562.aspx). Files are encrypted using the creator's password, so if the web application is running under your user account, this would be a convenient solution.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question.  You ask where to "hide" a key, but unless I'm missing something, `.bash_profile` isn't a hiding place.  What are your actual requirements?